# XLSX to PDF programmatically (Java)

Tags: java, pdf, xlsx

I have an XLSX file and i need to convert it to a equivalent pdf.  I tried out many ways, from  XLSX to HTML to PDF, using onlineconverter and libraries (including `iText`, `FlyingSource`, `Apache POI`) but no one worked fine, since text formatting gets lost.

I thought to another solution, use LibreOffice to print it as a PDF. I saw online it would be possible, but i did not understand how. I know i have to install it, and that's ok....but than?

Comment: What about using Excel (.NET)? Do you have (unlisted) requirements that disqualify this?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the language...i have to do it in Java.

Comment: the most foolproof solution will be to create a .NET executable that using the Excel interop libraries, and then use Java to start that executable in a new process. Or use a Java/.NET bridge like [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com).